# using a background image using div Id

Tags: html, css

Basically I am trying to do whats device here :
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-position

Have my image in the background has an id on a div.

```css
#wrapper {
 height: 900px;
 width:  900px;
 border: solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#idbackground {
   background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/7h8ejPJ.png");
   width: 324px;
   height: 250px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position:center center;
 }
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="idbackground"></div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

instead of centering the image disappears..

Comment: Well it's not going to work here since the link to your image doesn't exist. Is the path on your actual page correct? Checked the console for errors?

Comment: is the coding sound though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon after your

`background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/7h8ejPJ.png")`

Also add `width` and `height` property to your image div to 100%.

```css
#wrapper {
 height: 900px;
 width:  900px;
 border: solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#idbackground {
   background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/7h8ejPJ.png"); /* add semicolon here*/      
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position:center center;
   width:100%;           /*add width*/
   height:100%;          /*add height*/
 }
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="idbackground"></div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem was you were setting a width and height and the image was wrapped within this, so the image was limited with in this boundaries and hence you see the part of image being not visible, and on scroll it completely gets hidden, because the image div is scrolled up..

Comment: You are today's hero.

Comment: Glad I could help :) @BlueHorse

Answer (score 0):

`background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/7h8ejPJ.png")` is missing `;` in the end of line.

Comment: made the mistake in the fiddle. still not displaying the image center center.

Comment: It's a `background-position: fixed;` what makes trouble with `background-position: center center;`. Well, I'm a little confused, never tried something like that before, but it seems like `background-position: fixed;` has same effect as `position: fixed;`. So, it goes for document size. Try to extend sizes of your `#idbackground`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a semi-colon at the end of the declaration ... It should be

```
#idbackground {
   background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/7h8ejPJ.png");
   ....
 }
```

The semi-colon is required to separate between each declaration. It's only allowed to be removed if the declaration is the last one.

Comment: made the mistake in the fiddle. still not displaying the image center center.

Answer (score 0):

This workes perfectly for me.

```
#idbackground {
 background: url(http://i.imgur.com/7h8ejPJ.png)
}
```

Comment: but who was " background-position:center center;" ?

Comment: @BlueHorse ive never used backgorund-position: center center; but i think background-position: center; would work the samme way. note that im not the best at css soo i can be wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Like Reddy said, make your `width` and `height` equal to `100%` in your image div.

Should you ever use a non-square image use `min-width` and `min-height` properties with a value of `100%` to square up to whichever axis is larger.

Also if you'd like you can save yourself typing by consolidating all your `background` properties into one shorthand `background` property like such...

```
     #idbackground {
       background: url("http://i.imgur.com/7h8ejPJ.png") no-repeat fixed center;
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
     }
```

The shorthand syntax for the `background` property is as follows...

```
background: [color] [url(img.jpg)] [repeat_value] [attachment_value] [position_value(s)];
```

Just make sure you include spaces between each value and replace the bracketed items with the corresponding `background-` prefixed value. If left out or blank they will just be set to their default values.

Thus, a cleaned up version would be...

```
    #wrapper {
      height: 900px;
      width:  900px;
      border: solid black;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    #idbackground {
      background: url("http://i.imgur.com/7h8ejPJ.png") no-repeat fixed center; /* consolidated background shorthand */
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

... with the same HTML markup.